# File downloading percenatge jumps in Android ProgressBar

Tags: android, download, android-progressbar

I have implemented the functionality of file downloading from server with the Progress bar showing the percentage of file downloaded, and it is working fine. But sometimes because of **small file size** and **high internet speed**, Progress bar percentage **jumps like from 20 to 50 or something**.

[image]

Any solution to this for showing the continuous progress percentage??
Thanks in advance.

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
        int count;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
            URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
            conection.connect();
            // getting file length
            int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

            // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

            // Output stream to write file
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/downloadedfile.jpg");

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                // publishing the progress....
                // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));

                // writing data to file
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            // flushing output
            output.flush();

            // closing streams
            output.close();
            input.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: this is happen because you are failing in calculating the size of the file.

Comment: thanks for quick response, but it is working fine when file size is large.. any clue..??

Comment: can you able to post the code too

Comment: Added the code snippet, sorry for late update.

Comment: It looks good, but when you are facing the issue, asking the size of the file.

Comment: No.. Everything works perfect unless the size of file is too small..?